# Migrate Oracle filed type RAW to Postgre SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this Oracle field type configure into Hibernate entity:

```
@Column(name = "NUMBER", columnDefinition = "RAW(16)")
private UUID number;
```

I get exception when I run the cone on PostgreSQL:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "raw" does not exist
```

What filed type should I use in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate only or is it with JPA?

Comment: I use Spring cloud with dependency `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'`

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a builtin UUID type that you can use and it's accessible from JPA.  Based on what you've posted it would be something like:

```
@Column(name = "NUMBER", columnDefinition = "UUID")
private UUID number;
```

When you create the table, you can use type of `uuid` for the column type.

Note that *generating* the UUID can be done by PostgreSQL though that's somewhat dependent on the version of PostgreSQL you're using.